# How to add ovs interface back to init namespace from custom one?

Tags: linux, networking, network-namespaces

Am creating an internal interface tap1 in ovs & add it to a custom namespace ns1.

```
ip netns add ns1
ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port br0 tap1
ip link set tap1 netns ns1
```

after am done using the interface I need to move it back to the init namespace. Deleting custom namespace should return the device to its original namespace I thought,  but thats not the way its working.

```
ip netns del ns1
```

After ns delete, the interface is removed but its still lingers in ovs-vsctl show. & it gives error on next time I try to create the interface.

How do I cleanly remove it from ovs as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:
`ip netns exec ns1 ip link set tap1 netns 1`

That'll return the interface to the root namespace.